# Modernizr/ yepnope execution order WRT jQuery + plugins troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modernizr, dynamic-script-loading

I'm getting my head around Modernizr polyfill loading today and running into some trouble. I like the idea of loading jQuery in parallell and so have the CDN URI (with a local fallback) up top. Then I get in to loading some polyfills which are all jQuery plugins that I was using prior to discovering Modernizr.

The trouble is, the plugins are smaller and load before jQuery is done and exocuted, so '$' and 'jQuery' objects both wind up undefined. The yepnope docs say that the loader is supposed to respect the execution order of dependant scripts despite parallell downlaoding, but following the sample syntax to the letter still produces the error.

Can y'all have a look at my code below and see where I'm wanting? This snippet lies directly under the Modernizer minimized code; which is situated in my `<head>`. FYI, there is a slew of effects jQuery code that also get loaded at the bottom of my `<body>`, but I want the polyfills to work before I go setting up the 'complete:' function for them.

```
    Modernizr.load([
  {
    load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js',
    complete: function () {
      if (!window.jQuery)
            Modernizr.load('js/jquery.1.7.1.min.js');

    }
  },
  {//Border Radius
    test : Modernizr.borderradius,
    nope : 'js/polyfills/jquery.curvycorners.js'
  },
  {//Text Shadow
    test: Modernizr.textshadow,
    nope: 'js/polyfills/jquery.textshadow.min.js',
    complete: function(){
        $(function(){
            $("h2").textShadow(); 
            $("h3").textShadow();
            $("a.facebook").textShadow();
            $("a.twitter").textShadow();
        });
    }
  },
  {//Box Shadow
    test: Modernizr.boxshadow,
    nope: 'js/polyfills/jquery.boxshadow.js'
  }
]);
```

Comment: Peep the yepnope docs:
"
-yepnope.js has the capability to do resource fallbacks and still download dependent scripts in parallel with the first. More clearly:
yepnope([{
  load: 'http:/­/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js',
  complete: function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
      yepnope('local/jquery.min.js');
    }
  }
}, {
  load: 'jquery.plugin.js',
  complete: function () {
    jQuery(function () {
      jQuery('div').plugin();
    });
  }
}]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and experimentation, it looks this is an issue with yepnope at a concept level. Because of the load timeline for jQuery, the plugins will always go looking for it before it is ready. While a nested load() in the jQuery test's complete function is one way to hack it, you're then looking at a decent amount of time that the user will see the page without polyfills. While this might be ok for form validation, it looks as bad as a FOUC when you're polyfilling `border-radius` and `text-shadow` the way I am in this example.

The best solution I found was to load jQuery via the HTML5 boilerplate method:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Then place a `Modernizr.load()` in the `$(document).ready();`. While this offsets most of the parallel-load optimization benefits of Modernizr, it maintains the yepnope progressive enhancement principal, lets you use Modernizr for HTML5 shimming (which is just tidy IMHO), and ensures that jQuery is definitely available for polyfills. An upshot too is that you can safely use `$()` selection in  the complete function, which can be handy.

Comment: At what point in the sequence do you include Modernizr? I've found that if I link to jQuery and Modernizr separately it seriously breaks my HTML5 layout in Safari (which is not complicated whatsoever). But if I load jQuery with Modernizr.load, my on-page scripts don't work (including $(window).load). Oh and I'm using a custom Modernizr to include yepnope.js.

Comment: I ended up following suit after an hour of hair pulling. Your explanation about the load timeline for jQuery makes as much sense of this mess as I'd hope to at this hour of the night. What's frustrating me is that it shows on yepnope's website this exact use case, which means it's working for someone (who's not me).

Comment: FYI, back when I was working on this I got into an exchange with Paul Irish about it. He basically said that while he could see how the behaviour is represented this way in the docs, Modernizr cannot do this since it is just a loader: it has no ability to queue scripts since it isn't notified when a script execution finishes and there is no way to set up chained tests to see when it finishes passively. Don't beat your head too much, focus on a linear load-order rather than trying to "Matrix" scripts in parallel.

Comment: Update: Looks like I was just ahead of the game ;) Modernizr has been updated to address this issue...
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr#new-asynchronous-event-listeners